# How to pass default values on node form through form_alter when using confirm_form?

Tags: forms, nodes

My confirm form should consists part of node form but with disabled fields. I mean after I submit node form I rebuild it and append confirm form in `hook_form_alter()`(Before it I change submit callback and set 'reduild' flag in `form_state` in it).

But this form not containing filled values. I guess this is because I make rebuild but as I know there is no other way to display confirm form.
So the question is how to do it? How to fill values filled on previous step?

First phase submit callback:

```
function mymodule_content_confirm_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['storage']['confirm'] = 'save';
  $form_state['storage']['values'] = $form_state['values'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  return;
}
```

Form alter the part where confirm form appends:

```
  $show_confirm_form = isset($form_state['storage']['confirm']);
  if ($show_confirm_form) {
    // We need this form for panels and we can't remove it so we just hide.
    foreach (element_children($form) as $id) {
      $element = &$form[$id];
      if (!empty($element['#type']) && in_array($element['#type'], array('hidden', 'value'))) {
        continue;
      }
      $element['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    }
    $message = t('Are you sure you want to save all these changes?');

    $form = confirm_form($form, t('Levels & Content'), current_path(), $message, t('Confirm'), t('Cancel'));
    $form['actions']['cancel']['#href'] = current_path();
    $form['actions']['cancel']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'button';
    $form['actions']['cancel']['#options']['path'] = current_path();
    $form['actions']['cancel']['#options']['query'] = $destination;

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('mobitek_custom_content_node_form_insert_values_submit', 'node_form_submit');
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to see the form values in your $form_state['values'] array?

Comment: Yes, I am. But in form array they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is my dirty solution of the problem, I use `$form_state['complte form']` instead `$form`:

```
$refill_fields = array(
  'form_build_id',
  'form_id',
  'form_token',
  '#id',
  '#token',
  '#build_id',
);
foreach ($refill_fields as $refill_field) {
  $form_state['complete form'][$refill_field] = $form[$refill_field];
}
```